# How to parse this JSON using Newton Soft for nested object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, nested, json.net

How to parse this JSON

using Newton Soft

I tried but gives me null as my modal should have class 1, 2, 3 ... 
but that's dynamic .So getting confuse.

Appreciate your help !

```js
{
"data": {
    "1": {
        "test": {
            "col1": "123",
            "col2": "name"
        }
    },
    "2": {
        "test": {
            "col1": "345",
            "col2": "name2"
        }
    },
    "3": {
        "test": {
            "col1": "456",
            "col2": "name3"
        }
    }
}
```

```csharp
class root 
{ 
    data data{get; set;};
}

class data
{ 
    List<object> innerObject {get; set;} //not sure as labels are dynamic 
} 

class test
{ 
    col1{get; set;} 
    col2{get; set;} 
} //Calling it in that way .. 

root r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<root>(result);
```

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: `class root
{
   data data{get; set;};
}

class data
{
    List<object> innerObject {get; set;}  //not sure as labels are dynamic
}

class test
{
  col1{get; set;}
  col2{get; set;}
}

//Calling it in that way ..
root r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<root>(result);`
in r i will get object of all json

I don;t know what should i write in data class so parse the inner node.

Comment: "data" isn't a json-array. It's an object. So you can't parse it as an array/list.

Comment: @MayankJhawar, can you please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34947044/edit) your question to include the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to parse a JSON object with custom property names:

```
public class Test
{
    public string col1 { get; set; }
    public string col2 { get; set; }
}

public class DataValue
{
    public Test test { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public RootObject() { this.data = new Dictionary<string, DataValue>(); }
    public Dictionary<string, DataValue> data { get; set; }
}
```

See [Deserialize a Dictionary](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDictionary.htm).

If you are *sure* the dictionary keys will always be numeric, you can use integer keys, and use a [`SortedDictionay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to order the values:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public RootObject() { this.data = new SortedDictionary<long, DataValue>(); }
    public SortedDictionary<long, DataValue> data { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[@dbc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34949588/497356) is a good option, but you have a few other options as well:

1. If you have control over the JSON that's being generated, make your life easier by using an Array if you can. It looks like what you would really want is this:

   ```
   {
       "data": [{
           "test": {
               "col1": "123",
               "col2": "name"
           }, {
           "test": {
               "col1": "345",
               "col2": "name2"
           }, /* etc */
       ]
   }
   ```

   This way, `data` represents an array and you can deserialize it as such:

   ```
   class Root 
   { 
       List<Data> Data  { get; set; };
   }

   class Data
   {
       Test Test { get; set; }
   }

   JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
   ```
2. You could force your JSON into an array structure using a custom converter. This is making a lot of assumptions about your JSON. For example, it's assuming that you have an object with a integer keys, with no spaces in between numbers:

   ```
   public class ObjectAsArrayConverter : JsonConverter 
   {
     public override bool CanConvert(Type type)
     {         
       return
         type.IsGenericType &&
         typeof(List<>) == type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() &&
         typeof(Data) == type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
     }

     public override object ReadJson(
       JsonReader reader,
       Type objectType,
       object existingValue,
       JsonSerializer serializer)
     {
       JObject obj = JObject.ReadFrom(reader).ToObject<JObject>();

       return obj.Properties()
         .Select(p => new { Index = int.Parse(p.Name), Value = obj[p.Name].ToObject<Data>() })
         .OrderBy(p => p.Index)
         .Select(p => p.Value)
         .ToList();
     }

     public override void WriteJson(
       JsonWriter writer,
       object value,
       JsonSerializer serializer)
     {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
     }

   }
   ```

   This would allow you to deserialize your JSON into this structure:

   ```
   class Root 
   { 
       public List<Data> Data {get; set;}
   }

   class Data
   {
       public Test Test { get; set; }
   }

   class Test
   { 
       public string Col1 {get; set;} 
       public string Col2 {get; set;}
   }
   ```

   **Example:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/e2Df7h

You might need to tweak the second suggestion, for example if you expect the array to be sparse you might want to make the code expect that.

Comment: Thanks alot everyone I done with using dictonary 

Dictionary<string, object> test = obj.response.data;