# Deserializing with a json file with inner classes with JSON.NET C#

Tags: c#-4.0, json.net

I have the following structure in my json file

```
  "missionName": "missionname",
  "thumb_image": "pics/mission-info.png",
   "uplinkPage": [
    {
        "RPC": {
            "name": "RPC",
            "rpc": "",
            "args": ""
        },
        "EXE": {
            "name": "app1",
            "prog": "",
            "args": ""
        },
        "VM": {
            "name": "VM",
            "name": "",
            "args": ""
        },
        "JAR": {
            "name": "JAR",
            "prog": "",
            "args": ""
        },
        "link": {
            "name": "somelink",
            "url": ""
        }
    }
],
```

for this I have the following class

```
 public class EXE
{
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string prog { get; set; }
   public string args { get; set; }
}

public class RPC
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string rpc { get; set; }
    public string args { get; set; }
}

public class VM
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string args { get; set; }
}

public class JAR
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string prog { get; set; }
    public string args { get; set; }
}

public class Link
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

 public class UplinkPage
{
    public VM[] vmList { get; set; }
    public EXE[] exeList { get; set; }
    public RPC[] rpcList { get; set; }
    public JAR[] jarList { get; set; }
    public Link[] linkList { get; set; }
}

 public class Rootobject
{
    public string missionName { get; set; }
    public string thumb_image { get; set; }     
    public Uplinkpage[] uplinkPage { get; set; }        
}
```

the uplinkPage section can have one or many of each of the EXE, RPC, VM .. sections. I have tried to add multiply sections like this

```
"EXE": {
            "1": {
                "name": "app1",
                "data-prog": "",
                "data-args": ""
            },
            "2": { 
                "name": "app2",
            "data-prog": "",
            "data-args": ""
            }
        }
```

when I do the deserialization as so

```
Rootobject page = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(File.ReadAllText("mission1.json"));
```

I get an object and I can read everything except if I have multiply values of the same type, I will only get one of them. If I declare sections as array

```
public EXE[] exeList { get; set; }
```

I will get the last one and if as

```
Dictionary<string,EXE> exeList {get; set;}
```

I will get the first one. I have noticed that when I use the dictionary the type of the EXE changes to EXE1.

So I was wondering what am I doing wrong? am I mission some thing here?

cheers,
es

Comment: Do you have control over the format of your JSON?

Comment: yes I have full control over it, but I think the one I am using is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have a JSON property that might be duplicated, it will be easiest to represent the value of that property as JSON [array](http://json.org/), rather than multiple properties with duplicated names.  I.e. instead of

```
{
    "EXE" : {"id":1},
    "RPC" : {"name":"a"},        
    "EXE" : {"id":2},
}
```

You want to do:

```
{
    "EXE" : [{"id":1}, {"id":2}],
    "RPC" : [{"name":"a"}]        
}
```

Similarly, in the `VM` class, `name` appears multiple times, so `name` should be an array as well:

```
public class VM
{
    public string [] name { get; set; }
    public string args { get; set; }
}
```

(It's not *impossible* to deserialize duplicated property names, just difficult, and requires a custom converter.  See [How to deserialize JSON with duplicate property names in the same object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714160/how-to-deserialize-json-with-duplicate-property-names-in-the-same-object).  Since you control your JSON format, I'd recommend avoiding this.  Using a nested object with indexed properties as you propose in your question is also an option; it is less difficult but still requires custom conversion.  See [How to parse this JSON using Newton Soft for nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947044/how-to-parse-this-json-using-newton-soft-for-nested-object/34949588#34949588).  But using a JSON array is easiest.)

Next, you need to tell Json.NET how to map c# property names to JSON property names when they are inconsistent.  For instance, in your JSON you have a property `"EXE"` but in c# the property name is `public EXE[] exeList { get; set; }`.  You can either rename the JSON properties, rename the c# properties, or make the mapping using [`[JsonProperty]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm):

```
public class UplinkPage
{
    [JsonProperty("VM")]
    public VM[] vmList { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("EXE")]
    public EXE[] exeList { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("RPC")]
    public RPC[] rpcList { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("JAR")]
    public JAR[] jarList { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("link")]
    public Link[] linkList { get; set; }
}
```

I notice also that your `EXE` object sometimes has a `"data-prog"` property, and sometimes just a `"prog"`.  You should standardize on one.

Thus your JSON should look like:

> ```
> {
>   "missionName": "missionname",
>   "thumb_image": "pics/mission-info.png",
>   "uplinkPage": [
>     {
>       "RPC": [
>         {
>           "name": "RPC",
>           "rpc": "",
>           "args": ""
>         }
>       ],
>       "EXE": [
>         {
>           "name": "app1",
>           "prog": "prog1",
>           "args": "args1"
>         },
>         {
>           "name": "app2",
>           "prog": "prog2",
>           "args": "args2"
>         }
>       ],
>       "VM": [
>         {
>           "name": [
>             "VM",
>             ""
>           ],
>           "args": ""
>         }
>       ],
>       "JAR": [
>         {
>           "name": "JAR",
>           "prog": "",
>           "args": ""
>         }
>       ],
>       "link": [
>         {
>           "name": "somelink",
>           "url": ""
>         }
>       ]
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```

And your classes should look like:

```
public class EXE
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string prog { get; set; }
    public string args { get; set; }
}

public class RPC
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string rpc { get; set; }
    public string args { get; set; }
}

public class VM
{
    public string [] name { get; set; }
    public string args { get; set; }
}

public class JAR
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string prog { get; set; }
    public string args { get; set; }
}

public class Link
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class UplinkPage
{
    [JsonProperty("VM")]
    public VM[] vmList { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("EXE")]
    public EXE[] exeList { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("RPC")]
    public RPC[] rpcList { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("JAR")]
    public JAR[] jarList { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("link")]
    public Link[] linkList { get; set; }
}

public class Rootobject
{
    public string missionName { get; set; }
    public string thumb_image { get; set; }
    public UplinkPage[] uplinkPage { get; set; }
}
```

prototype [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Lz9Qwe).